# underline in front of enumerate item

Tags: enumerate, rules

I'm creating a simple multiple choice quiz using enumerate and would like a 1cm underline in front of each `\item` for students to write their response. How can I do that?

This is what I have so far:

[image]

This is what I would like:

```
_____ 2. Which is the best estimate...
```

Comment: Could you share "what [you] have so far"? It would make it easier for a solution to be tailored to your specifications.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `label` of the upper level `enumerate` using [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem,tabularx}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}% For this example

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label={\rule{1cm}{.4pt}\arabic*.},leftmargin=*]
  \item Which is the best estimate of the square root of~$30$?

  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ *{4}{X} }
    a) $5.2$ & b) $5.5$ & c) $5.8$ & d) $15$
  \end{tabularx}

  \item Which is the best estimate of the square root of~$30$?

  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ *{4}{X} }
    a) $5.2$ & b) $5.5$ & c) $5.8$ & d) $15$
  \end{tabularx}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

The 1cm rule is from the left margin of the text block, butting up to the enumeration. You can insert a space if needed just before `\arabic*`.

Answer (score 0):

I used this as the code to recreate what you've got:

```
\documentclass{exam}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

\question Which is the best estimate of $\sqrt{30}$?

\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice 5.2
\choice 5.5
\choice 5.8
\choice 15
\end{oneparchoices}

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

I used the following code to create an alternate solution:

```
\documentclass{exam}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

\question Which is the best estimate of $\sqrt{30}$?

\begin{oneparcheckboxes}
\choice 5.2
\choice 5.5
\choice 5.8
\choice 15
\end{oneparcheckboxes}
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

This second piece of code produces

[image]

where there are handy circles for students to fill in the answer. Another piece of information of note is [the exam package documentation](http://www-math.mit.edu/~psh/exam/examdoc.pdf).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Does this answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do this by:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{enumerate}
  \item 
  First item.
  \item 
  Second one.
  \item [\underline{\hspace{.4in}} \stepcounter{enumi}\arabic{enumi}.]
  This one.
  \item
  Last one.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Also I recommend using `exam` style for such tasks.

Comment: Why not just use `1cm` rather than `.4in`?

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I got used to that maybe!

Comment: Also note the questions asks to have a rule "in front of each `\item`". Finally, there's no need to load [`lineno`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lineno).